# Error: No named parameter with the name 'onSelectNotification'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-local-notification

```
class HelperNotification {

  static Future<void> initialize(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    var androidInitialize = new AndroidInitializationSettings('notification_icon');
    var iOSInitialize = new DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings, onSelectNotification:(String? payload) async {

      try{
        if(payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {

          // Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getOrderDetailsRoute(int.parse(payload)));
        }else {

          //  Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getNotificationRoute());
        }
      }catch (e) {}
      return;
    });
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,

    );
```

I found that there was an update with the local notification package but i was trying to implement it and was unsuccessful can you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Since version 10.0.0 of the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin, they removed `onSelectNotification` parameter. You can read more about it in their changelog:

> **Breaking change**
> callbacks have now been reworked. There are now the
> following callbacks and both will pass an instance of the
> NotificationResponse class onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: invoked
> only when the app is running. This works for when a user has selected
> a notification or notification action. **This replaces the
> `onSelectNotification` callback that existed before.** For notification
> actions, the action needs to be configured to indicate the the app or
> user interface should be shown on invoking the action for this
> callback to be invoked i.e. by specifying the
> DarwinNotificationActionOption.foreground option on iOS and the
> showsUserInterface property on Android. On macOS and Linux, as there's
> no support for background isolates it will always invoke this callback
> onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: invoked on a background
> isolate for when a user has selected a notification action. This
> replaces the onSelectNotificationAction callback

Read more here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/changelog